# sed regex replacing too many characters?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm using the following command with sed : `sed s/1[^\.]/2/g test`

I want to replace every 1 with a 2 except the one followed by a point. It works fine.

But in my file I've got a `{{1e}}` that is replaced by `{{2}}`.

Why does sed delete the `e`?

PS: I'm a beginner with regex so it might be an obvious mistake.

Comment: I think sed interprets it as "replace the following 2 characters with "2". (1 followed by any letter other than "."). I am a beginner as well, so not quite sure what the actual fix is.

Comment: Your regex matches two chars, first is "1" and secondd is whatevere, just not "."; You should use capture the subpattern after "1" and include it in substitution pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture the character after `1` and insert it again after `2`:

```
sed 's/1\([^.]\)/2\1/g' test
```

The only problem is `1` at the end of line. You can replace it by `2` with

```
s/1$/2/
```

Comment: Thx for your help ! I've no 1 at end of line so it won't be a problem :)

Comment: `sed 's/1\([^.]\|$\)/2\1/g' test` would cater for the end-of-line condition too. N.B. I don't think the `.` needs to backslashed in the character class.

Comment: Supposing I need to add the following condition do not replace the `1` followed by `.` `em` or `p` but I want to replace the ones followed by  `e` I tried `sed 's/1\([^(em|\.|p)]\)/$i\\1/g' test` but the one followed by `e` are not replaced.